# db_index in django as raw sql query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, psql

Can anyone specify the raw sql query executing for a `db_index = True` in django, I have a model field which I need to alter with db_index as True, but my rds server crashes since a lot of db process runs in parallel,

```
url = models.CharField(db_index=True,max_length=100, blank=True)
```

What will be the raw psql query for this alteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `db_index=True` to the model and then run `makemigrations`, you can use [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate) to show the SQL command for your database backend.

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate my_app 000X_migration_name
```

For postgres, this will generate SQL similar to the following:

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Alter field url on mymodel
--
CREATE INDEX "myapp_mymodel_url_2e338adc" ON "myapp_mymodel" ("url");
CREATE INDEX "myapp_mymodel_url_2e338adc_like" ON "myapp_mymodel" ("url" varchar_pattern_ops);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: what does `2e338adc` stands for? Is that any generated id or can I use any random one when I execute this query